# Linux mv: target is not a directory

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm trying to move all js files in a folder to another folder with a makefile script, but i'm getting a "target is not a directory" error. All other threads i've seen involve renaming but i only want to move files, here's the snippet:

```
rm -rf app/assets/webpack_bundles/*.js;
mv app/assets/webpack_bundles_build/*.js app/assets/webpack_bundles/;
mv: target 'app/assets/webpack_bundles/' is not a directory
```

I know the fix is probably something miniscule but i've been stuck with this for an hour now. Any help?

Comment: Nvm fixed it with mkdir app/assets/webpack_bundles/ im stupid lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because your target directory is not available.

```
mkdir -p app/assets/webpack_bundles/
mv app/assets/webpack_bundles_build/*.js app/assets/webpack_bundles/
```